# How to get request parameter to an array in Java, in the style of PHP and Rails?

Tags: java, parameters, request

The situation is as follows:

```
page.jsp?var[0]=foo&var[1]=bar
```

How can this be retrieved in an array in Java?

The following:

```
page.jsp?var=foo&var=bar
```

I know can be retrieved using request.getParameterValues("var")

Any solutions for the above though?

Comment: Does it have to be in a GET request?

Comment: No, it can be POST or GET, as long as it's retrievable via the request object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map<Integer,String> index2value=new HashMap<Integer,String>();

for (Enumeration e = request.getParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements() ;)
 {
 String param= e.nextElement().toString();
 if(!param.matches("var\[[0-9]+\]")) continue;
 int index= (here extract the numerical value....)
 index2value.put(index,request.getParameter(param));
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was hoping there would have been a more "automatic" way. But this will have to do. 

Thanks.

Comment: param.matches("var\[[0-9]+\]") does not compile.        Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )

Answer (score 4):

```
HashMap m = request.getParameterMap();
Set k = m.keySet();
Set v = m.entrySet();
Object o[] = m.entrySet().toArray();
```

That will get you a Map call m with K,V pairs and both a set of keys and set of values. You can iterate those sets almost like an array. You can also use toArray to turn it into an array.